Prove this recurrence relation for $I_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname du}{(1+u^2)^n}$

Problem. Define $I_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname du}{(1+u^2)^n}$. Prove that $(2n-1)I_n=2nI_{n+1}$.

I tried to integrate by parts two times (the second time in the "$\cdots$")
\begin{align*}
I_n&=\int_0^\infty\frac1{(1+u^2)^n}\cdot1\operatorname du=\left[\frac1{(1+u^2)^n}\cdot u\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{-2nu}{(1+u^2)^{n+1}}\cdot u\operatorname du\\
&=0+\int_0^\infty\frac{2nu^2}{(1+u^2)^{n+1}}\operatorname du=n\int_0^\infty\frac{2u}{(1+u^2)^2}\cdot\frac u{(1+u^2)^{n-1}}\operatorname du\\
&=\cdots=nI_n-n(n-1)\int_0^\infty\frac{2u^2}{(1+u^2)^{n+1}}\operatorname du.
\end{align*}
The second time wasn't really meaningful as it just brought be to where I had been.

A very minor point: the integral is only convergent for $ n>1/2$. Also, this integral can be related to the gamma function as demonstrated here. This is perhaps not very helpful here, though, since presumably one should not make use of gamma function properties.

The recurrence relation was mentioned in an answer about $I_{2012}/I_{2011}$ and another answer about the corresponding indefinite integral.

Your solution is fine. You overlooked the simple relation $u^2=(u^2+1)-1$ which leads to the conclusion.

Integration by parts:
$$\begin{aligned}I_n&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm du}{(1+u^2)^n}\\&=\left.\frac{u}{(1+u^2)^n}\right|_{u=0}^\infty+2n\int_0^\infty\frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm du\\
&=2n\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm du}{(1+u^2)^n}-2n\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm du}{(1+u^2)^{n+1}}\\I_n&=2nI_n-2n I_{n+1}\\\color{red}{\implies(2n-1)I_n}&\color{red}{=2nI_{n+1}\qquad\text{proved.}}\end{aligned}
$$
Note: The integral $I_n$ converges only for $2n>1$ or $n>\frac12$, i.e., $\frac1n<2$, and thus $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{(1+u^2)^n}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(\frac{u^{\frac1n-2}}{1+u^{-2}}\right)^n=0$. This limit is $\infty$ for $n<\frac12$, and $1$ for $n=\frac12$. The integral does not converge for $n\leq\frac12$.
